# What's the meaning of "give Caesar his due"?

Tags: meaning

I read an article, it said: "Let's give Caesar his due". What's the meaning of

> give Caesar his due

Comment: [give someone their due](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/due?q=due#due__20)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s from Matthew 22:20–22

> 20 And he saith unto them, Whose is this image and superscription?
>
> 21 They say unto him, Caesar’s. Then saith he unto them, Render therefore unto Caesar the things which are Caesar’s; and unto God the things that are God’s.
>
> 22 When they had heard these words, they marvelled, and left him, and went their way.

But what is “means” cannot be assigned in your situation without more context. A loose phrase means little.

Comment: To clarify, Caesar's head used to be on coins. The bible passage can be read as meaning "Yeah, let secular authority (the emperor) have its due (taxes), but you owe God something too, OK?" As tchrist says, what this means when quoted is highly dependent on context.